# SQL BACKUP and Restore Full backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two full backups of different dates first full backup is of date lets suppose 21-05-2017 and I have restored that backup to client machine (RESTORE WITH NO RECOVERY) and now I got second full back on date : 26-05-2017 , now I want to restore that full backup on previous restored Full back on my client machine.
Any one tell me what are advantages and disadvantages of restoring full backup over full backup .right now I am deleting previous restored database and again restore latest full database but it consume time . 
Any one tell me what are advantages and disadvantages of restoring full backup over full backup.  ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, No advantage of restoring an older full backup and then restoring another newer backup on top of that. Your restore of the newer full backup will overwrite the restore of the older backup.

Disadvantages: Simply waste of time and recourses.

Comment: i am restoring differential database on restoreable DB on daily baises and at the end of week i need to get the full back up... what i am doing right now is that i am first deleting previous restoreable DB and then restore new Full backup .

Answer (score 1):

Restoring new Full Backup on top of old Full Backup will overwrite the older backup restore.